# ¿Cómo recuperar el valor de un bitmap que retorna un método de una WebApi, desde una aplicación Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, bitmap, webapi

Tengo una WebApi, dónde un método retorna un Bitmap, quisiera poder recuperar el bitmap del lado de la aplicación Android Xamarin, soy nuevo en ésto de WebApi, y tengo un método donde recupere un Json, pero para un bitmap no tengo idea.

Aquí mi método de la WebApi

```
public Bitmap CodigoQR(string Texto)
        {
            QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
            qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeEncodeMode = ThoughtWorks.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE;
            qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeScale = 4;
            qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeErrorCorrect = ThoughtWorks.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.M;
            // La versión "0" calcula automáticamente el tamaño
            qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeVersion = 0;
            // --------- Forzar una determinada version -----------
            // En caso de querer forzar una determinada version (tamaño) el siguiente código devuelve la
            // versión mínima para el texto que se quiere códificar
            // Dim iVersion As Integer = AdjustQRVersion(TextBox1.Text, qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeErrorCorrect)
            int qrBackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255).ToArgb();
            int qrForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0).ToArgb();
            qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeBackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(qrBackColor);
            qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeForegroundColor = Color.FromArgb(qrForeColor);
            Bitmap myImg = qrCodeEncoder.Encode(Texto, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            return myImg;
        }
```

Y Aquí tengo mi método de la Aplicación Android Xamarin, donde intento recuperar el valor del bitmap

```
public void ImagenQR()
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient("http://portalclientewa.azurewebsites.net/api/Values/");
        var request = new RestRequest("CodigoQR", Method.GET);
        request.Timeout = 300000;
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddParameter("Texto", ImageQR);
        //En ésta ultima linea es donde recupero el valor que me retorna la WepApi, pero no tengo idea como recuperar el valor del BitMap
        var temp = client.Execute<List<string>>(request).Data;
    }
```

Comment: una duda, estas en Xamarin, con codigo .net en el device, la libreria QRCodeEncoder no puedes usarla directa, porque necesitas invocar un webapi para que solo genere la imagen ? si la libreria es compatible con framework que usas en Xamarin deberias poder usarla

Comment: No me deja usar la librería QRCodeEncoder en la aplicación Xamarin Android, me marca error, me pide agregar la librería SystemDrawing, Version 2.0.0.0, pero no me deja agregarla, cuando la intento agregar me salta otro error @LeandroTuttini, así que la wepApi, me sirve para traer la imagen, y algunos otros métodos más

Comment: edite la respuesta, agregue una libreria que puedes evalaur para generar el QR directo en xamarin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendaria que si usas webapi la imagen la envies como `base64` de esta forma sera un string con la imagen encodeada lo que envias

Estarias usando:

[Convert.ToBase64String()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

en Xamarin obtendrias desde el webapi ese base64 y aplicarias la conversion

[Convert.FromBase64String()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx)

para obtener nuevamente el `byte[]` de la imagen

---

Sino otra alternativa es enviar el `stream`, similar a lo que se menciona aqui

[Upload and Download Files with Web API and Azure Blob Storage](http://arcware.net/upload-and-download-files-with-web-api-and-azure-blob-storage/)

como veras es necesario definir el `Content.Headers` indicando el `ContentType`

---

Si necesitas solo generar el QR desde Xamarin evalua la libreria [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://components.xamarin.com/view/zxing.net.mobile)

[QR CODE Generator: Xamarin.Forms](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e4bad6/qr-code-generator-xamarin-forms/)

esta es compatible con Xamarin y no necesitaras del webapi para generar la imagen del QR